# TWO linux commands executed in background called by PHP exec() function

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, exec

I try to execute two linux commands in background by single php exec() call.

My first command makes some files backup:

```
cp -r ../source ../destination
```

Second command creates a file "DONE.txt" when backup is complete:

```
touch ../destination/DONE.txt
```

Moreover I base on php manual and use following background exec() call:

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid '.$twoCommands.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

The whole code is bellow:

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid { cp -r ../source ../destination && touch ../destination/DONE.txt; } > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

And... it doesn't work:) But why?

If I use only one command:

```
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid cp -r ../source ../destination > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

It works well:)

Comment: If you don't redirect the errors to `/dev/null`, what errors do you see? Are you sure about what the current directory is? Have you permissions? Etc, etc

Comment: If I use only one command:
exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid cp -r ../source ../destination > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
It works well:)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you're trying to make this so complicated. `nohup` and `setsid` are two completely separate functions, not arguments you pass to `exec`. Nor do you even need to call `exec` in the command itself; that's the point of using `exec` in PHP. Output redirection is only necessary if you need the PHP script to continue in the background after the `exec` call rather than waiting for it to finish.

```
[root@test~]# ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   24 Jun 27 13:40 source
[root@test~]# ll source
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jun 27 13:40 1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jun 27 13:40 2
[root@test~]# php -a
Interactive shell

php > exec("cp -r ./source ./destination && touch ./destination/DONE.txt");
php > exit
[root@test~]# ll destination/
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jun 27 13:44 1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jun 27 13:44 2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jun 27 13:44 DONE.txt
[root@test~]#
```